# Mule - Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[]

Tags: exception, mule, mule-studio, payload

I have a flow in Mule where I'm reading in a file, logging it's content and then outputting to a new file. Everytime I try and run the flow I get the following error immediately after Mule has identified my input file:

```
INFO  2014-03-21 12:23:45,706 [[processes].inputFileConnector.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: /input/file_203812.dat
ERROR 2014-03-21 12:23:45,725 [[processes].inputFileConnector.receiver.01] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException)
  org.mule.routing.MessageFilter:100 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/routing/filter/FilterUnacceptedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException: Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[]
    at org.mule.routing.MessageFilter.filterUnacceptedException(MessageFilter.java:100)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.handleUnaccepted(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:62)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:48)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I've been trying to fix this for a while with very little success so any help would be appreciated. Here's a copy of my config file for reference:

```
<file:connector name="outputFileConnector" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="inputFileConnector" workDirectory="/processing" 
    workFileNamePattern="#[message.outboundProperties.originalFilename]" moveToDirectory="/backup" 
    moveToPattern="#[function:datestamp:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS]_#[message.outboundProperties.originalFilename]"
    streaming="false" doc:name="File"/>

<flow name="MainFlow" doc:name="MainFlow">

    <file:inbound-endpoint name="b2bFileEndpoint" path="/input" pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="inputFileConnector" doc:name="Input Trigger">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="file_\d{6}.dat" caseSensitive="true"/> 
    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>      
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" doc:name="Debug"/>

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/output" connector-ref="outputFileConnector" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

    <!-- Error handling -->
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger level="ERROR" message="There has been an error" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>

</flow>
```

**UPDATE**

Bizarrely, if I change the moveToPattern to: `#[message.outboundProperties.orginalFilename]` the issue goes away. This isn't an option as I need the processed file to have a datestamp appended. Very confused over this issue now...

Comment: Mule version? I can not reproduce this error using latest Studio.

Comment: I'm using studio version 3.5.0 and standalone version 3.4.0 - also, for reference, the file I'm trying to use is a .dat file, the contents of which is a single line containing 6 digits

Answer (score 0):

See here is one of my example ... it's working fine ... please modify and add catch block as per your requirement :-

```
<file:connector name="File_Input_Global" workDirectory="E:\backup\test_workingDir" workFileNamePattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yyyy]_#[header:originalFilename].dat" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="File_output_Global" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="FileRegularExpFlow1" doc:name="FileRegularExpFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Input_Global" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="aa.txt" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test_out" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_output_Global" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

You can see the file in the working directory has datestamp as well as original file name ... Please vote the answer if it helped you

Comment: Thanks @Anirban. However, this solution doesn't specify a moveToDirectory, which is where I think my error is coming from?